# Thumbnail Grid shows up in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site that uses a thumbnail grid (9 posts, 3 posts wide, responsive ) the featured image on each post creates the grid.

My code that controls the grid is

```
<?php
/**
 * controls main grid images
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-md-4 col-sm-4 pbox '); ?>>

    <div class = "box-ovrly">
      <h2 class="box-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <div class="box-meta"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
    </div>

    <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 560, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>

    <?php if($image) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
    <?php endif; ?> 

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

It creates a grid but it shows up in the reverse order (9 to 1, instead of 1 to 9) This wouldn't be a huge deal but I have 'next' and 'previous' buttons which don't co-ordinate to the post.

Ex. on my first post the 'previous' button shows up cause it thinks its on the 9th post, etc.

the back/next menu is created with the following

```
function web2feel_content_nav( $nav_id ) {
global $wp_query, $post;

// Don't print empty markup on single pages if there's nowhere to navigate.
if ( is_single() ) {
    $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( $post->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
    $next = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

    if ( ! $next && ! $previous )
        return;
}

// Don't print empty markup in archives if there's only one page.
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) )
    return;

$nav_class = ( is_single() ) ? 'post-navigation' : 'paging-navigation';

?>
<nav role="navigation" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $nav_id ); ?>" class="<?php echo $nav_class; ?> row">
    <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'web2feel' ); ?></h1>

<?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

    <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous col-xs-6">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'web2feel' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?>
    <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next col-xs-6">%link</div>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'web2feel' ) . '</span>' ); ?>

<?php elseif ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) ) : // navigation links for home, archive, and search pages ?>

    <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
    <div class="nav-previous col-md-6"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'web2feel' ) ); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
    <div class="nav-next col-md-6"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'web2feel' ) ); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</nav><!-- #<?php echo esc_html( $nav_id ); ?> -->
<?php
}
```

Comment: Share the wordpress query parameters and code from the place where starts your loop ( the line before foreach(have_posts()) )

Comment: What's the CSS for the grid?  Is there a `float:right` in there some place?

Comment: I managed to solve it, It may be messy and wrong but it works. switched previous_post_links and next_post_links in the 'is_single' loop. Seems to work for what I need